# Mysql Order by not working

Tags: mysql

I have a  MySQL table |source|destination|distance. The postcode can be either in the source or destination column like this. When I try an order by it outputs just as it is displayed below and not with the last row first . How can I solve this please.

1. source | destination | distance
2. DYRFG  |   DV116BL  |    5.6
3. DH34G  |   DV116BL  |    4.0
4. DV116  |  DH5ADZZ    |    7.0

   ```
   Select
   healthcare.address_matrix.*
   From
   healthcare.address_matrix
   Where
   (healthcare.address_matrix.source_postcode = 'Dv116BL') Or
   (healthcare.address_matrix.dest_postcode = 'Dv116BL')
   Order By
   healthcare.address_matrix.distance
   ```

Comment: What kind of field is distance?

Comment: @diEcho The sample output isn't ascending, so changing to `DESC` probably won't produce the desired result, either.

Comment: What happens when you remove the where clause? Or if you use the short field namens?

Comment: @Pieter21 Why would either of those make a difference in ordering?

Comment: Someone was nice enough to edit your question to make the table and code readable. Why did you mess it up?

Comment: It may help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: The distance field is miles

Comment: What is the field type? Float? Varchar?

Comment: I thought it was more readable. That's all

Comment: The distance column is varchar

Comment: try to alter table and set distance as float

Comment: I altered distance column to float. I played with the numbers and the order by is working now. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

If it is not picking up the order by field properly the order will be random. 
I think it will help if you explicitly name and rename the fields you select and order. Not use the * construct.

Answer (score 0):

Since distance is a varchar, you should try to order as if it is a float:

```
Order By CAST(`healthcare.address_matrix.distance` AS SIGNED) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the column to `decimal`

```
Select healthcare.address_matrix.* From healthcare.address_matrix Where (healthcare.address_matrix.source_postcode = 'Dv116BL') Or (healthcare.address_matrix.dest_postcode = 'Dv116BL') Order By CAST(healthcare.address_matrix.distance AS DECIMAL(5,2)) DESC
```